# What's the easiest way to access data outside the mapped array in a map state in a step function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a map state in my step function whose input looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "foobar",
  "specs": [...]
}
```

When configuring the map state I set `"ItemsPath": "$.specs"` to run the function once for each element of "specs":

```
        "MyMap": {
            "Type": "Map",
            "Next": "FirstLambdaInMap",
            "ItemsPath": "$.specs",
            "Iterator": { ...
```

What's the simplest way for me to update the state machine description so that the `"name": "foobar"` setting will also be exposed to the lambda called in the map state? Do I just have to update the input format of my data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing inputs to lambda function inside Map state of step function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77038901/passing-inputs-to-lambda-function-inside-map-state-of-step-function)